# reading 2 strings on each line from the input and printing them in loop in C

Tags: c, string, io, printf

I am trying to write a program that read input (where there are 2 words on each line) and I want to print those words. but it gives me a strange output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    char word1[21], word2[21], text[5005];
    int line = 0, i;
    while (fgets(text, sizeof(text), stdin))
    { 
        sscanf(text, "%s %s", &word1[line], &word2[line]);
        line++;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < line; i++)
       {
           printf("%s %s", word1, word2);
           printf("\n");
        }
    return 0;
}
```

when I input for example:

```
dog cat
black white
```

the output is:

```
dblack cwhite
dblack cwhite
```

how do I make an output like this?

```
dog cat
black white
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your `word1[line]` has only 1-character length buffer. You should allocate arrays of arrays of characters.

Also don't forget to print each lines.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    char word1[21][5005], word2[21][5005], text[5005];
    int line = 0, i;
    while (fgets(text, sizeof(text), stdin))
    { 
        sscanf(text, "%s %s", word1[line], word2[line]);
        line++;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < line; i++)
       {
           printf("%s %s", word1[i], word2[i]);
           printf("\n");
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this has a serious problem when the input contains more that 21 lines.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1.

`word1` and `word2` are just arrays of `char`:

```
char word1[21], word2[21];
```

Thus:

```
while (fgets(text, sizeof(text), stdin))
{ 
    sscanf(text, "%s %s", &word1[line], &word2[line]);
    line++;
}
```

will write input strings of different lines successively to the next character element in `wordN`, not to another `word` memory.

This causes the

```
dblack cwhite
```

output.

`black` is written starting at the second element of `word1`, where `dog` was stored before, starting at the first element. `white` is written starting at the second element of `word2`, where `cat` was stored before, starting at the first element. Both use the same memory excluding the first element.

#### 2.

`while (fgets(text, sizeof(text), stdin))` - The condition will always be true if not an `I/O` error has happened.

---

If you just want to endlessly print out 2 words given as input for each line (as you said) and  use `fgets()` for catching, use this instead. It is way more compact:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char word1[50], word2[50], line_text[50];

    while (fgets(line_text, sizeof(line_text), stdin))
    { 
        sscanf(line_text, "%s %s", word1, word2);
        printf("%s %s\n", word1, word2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
hello world
dog cat
black white
apple banana
```

Output:

```
hello world 
dog cat
black white
apple banana
```